# Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument when reading csv files

Tags: r

I have seen posts about this issue before, but none exactly like the issue that I am having. This code has been working for me with previous versions of R. I recently updated my R and R Studio to versions R 4.2.1 and RStudio Desktop 2022.07.1+554, and now I am getting the subject error when I try to read in my data files. The data files all have the same filenames. I point to the top level directory and then the code goes down through the folder structure and pulls out all of the data files to be used by the rest of the program.

Also want to mention that I am not that well versed in R, so I may not be doing everything in the best manner. Any suggestions that anyone can provide would be most appreciated.

Here is my code to select the top level folder, search through those folders and then read the files which is generating the error.

```
wd <<- choose.dir(caption = "Select top level folder where your data is located")
setwd(wd)

#List the full path and filename of all files in the working directory and sub-directories that starts 
#with "DINum" and ends with ".csv"
out_files <- list.files(pattern = "^DINum(.*)csv$", recursive = TRUE)

# initialise list to store csv files
list.data <- NULL

# create a loop to read in data
for (i in 1:length(out_files))
{
  list.data[[i]]<-read.csv(out_files[i], check.names = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: if not too sensitive, could you provide the output of `dput(out_files)` just before the loop runs?

Comment: I didn't get much of anything. I guess that is the issue, but I don't know why this used to work. Using the dput command, I got character(0). I did a view(dput(out_files) and it said "No data available in table"

Comment: this suggests the issue is with the `list.files` command, `charactor(0)` suggests it's not reading the file system correctly. I'm not near my laptop at the moment, but I would take a look at getting that to return something first

Comment: Correction. I changed the filename that it is looking for in what I posted due to sensitivity of the subject matter and forgot to change it back when I ran the dput command. This actually does seem to be working when I use the correct filenames! I get:  c("csv_190727_1/Vul/DINum.csv", "csv_190727_2/Vul/DINum.csv", "csv_190727_3/Vul/DINum.csv"). I apologize for my earlier stupidity.

Comment: OK, just took a look at this, your code is fine, the error is probably with the csv files themselves. does it immediately break, or only after reading a few files? Could you give the structure of the csv files? or a few lines of anonymised data?

Comment: What does `readLines(out_files[1], 5)` or `readLines("csv_190727_1/Vul/DINum.csv", 5)` look like?

Comment: I believe I have narrowed the issue down, but I don't know why it is happening. If I only have 1 data file in my folder structure, it works fine. If I have more than 1 data file, I get the error.  I did add the line "list.data<-list()". I had that previously in my code, but while playing around trying to fix this problem, I apparently removed it. This is a program that I have been using for a couple of years now. I only started having this issue after upgrading R and R Studio. Has there been any change anyone knows about that might cause this? I will run the other suggestions and post results.

Comment: As far as posting an example of a data file, I sanitized it, but not sure how to best post it here. The rows are very long. Any suggestions?

Comment: I ran view(readlines(out_files[1], 5)) and I get my column headers, followed by the first 4 lines of data. This appears to be working as I would expect.

Comment: Are you sure that the data hasn't changed in any way? Can you take the file/folder that works and copy and paste it to see if it works with two copies of the same file?

Comment: I made a copy of the data directory that works so that I have two identical copies of the data folders. I still get the error.

Comment: That's really odd could you upload an anonymised header and first row/s of the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have been using read.csv from base R. I installed the readr package and tried read_csv and it is working fine. Not sure why read.csv no longer works, but from what I read online, read_csv is a better choice anyway for large data files. Thanks to everyone that tried to help me. I appreciate your time!